# In ggplot2 on log10 scale, can axis label accuracy vary?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm drawing a plot with a log10 x-axis, with limits from 0.01 to 100. By default, the axis is displayed in scientific notation.

If I define the label using `comma_format()`, it the ticks mark 0.01, 0.10, 1.00, 10.00 and 100.00.

However, I want the labels to be 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100.

Is there any way to vary with accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gsub()` with a regex pattern to remove trailing zeroes and optionally a separator.

The expression below has the following meaning:

- `0+$` one or more zeroes at the end of the string.
- `\\.?` possibly a period (the dashes indicate literal periods instead of the regex wildcard). By placing this before the zeroes, we only seek to remove periods followed by zeroes, which excludes e.g. `0.01`.

```r
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 10^seq(-2, 2, length.out = 10))

ggplot(df, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10(
    labels = ~ gsub("\\.?0+$", "", comma(.x))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>